# Angular 2 не работает директива в импортированном модуле

Tags: angular2, angular-directive, компоненты

Привет, сразу к делу:

Использую Angular-cli v. 1.0.0

Есть главный модуль:

```
@NgModule({
    imports: [
       CommonModule,
       BrowserModule,
       DashboardModule,
       ..... another modules .....
    ],
    declarations: [
       AppComponent, 
       HeaderComponent, 
       BeautyPriceDirective
    ],
    bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule {}
```

В него подключается BeautyPriceDirective, обычная такая атрибутная директивка.

И есть второй модуль, который импортируется в главный  (AppModule):

```
@NgModule({
    imports: [
        CommonModule,
        BrowserModule
    ],
    declarations: [
        DashboardComponent, 
        DashboardTilesComponent, 
    ],
})
export class DashboardModule { }
```

Проблема в том, что директива не отрабатывает в компоненте DashboardComponent и во всех вложенных в него, но спокойненько себе работает в HeaderComponent, который объявлен в первом модуле.

Так же, если DashboardComponent объявить в первом модуле, то директива в нем отрабатывает отлично.

Скорее всего есть какой-то совсем не хитрый способ "пробросить" директивы и другие данные в импортированный модуль... или все-таки нет и нужно вот так делать огромный список компонентов?

P.S. когда я пытаюсь поместить известную директиву в импортированный модуль - Angular ругается на то, что это объявление уже указано в двух модулях.

Comment: какая версия ангуляра? попробуй в AppModule добавить секцию `exports: [BeautyPriceDirective]`

Comment: в идеале сделать [mcve] На [plnkr.co](http://plnkr.co/edit/?p=catalogue)

Comment: @Grundy, npm angular --v говорит мне, что я юзаю версию 3.10.8
exports: увы не помог, а пробовал (

Comment: это он что-то другое говорит, у ангуляра в версии первая цифра 2.

Comment: @Grundy, да я тоже подумал, что это было бы очень странно, если бы было правдой. Но что-то я не могу найти версию, точно не ниже 2.1.0 (из package.json).
Пробовал смотреть в node_modules, в файлах самого angular, но там тоже пусто.
на plnkr последняя доступная версия - 2, в ней еще поддерживаются такие вещи как directives: [] и всяческие декораторы Template, которые, кажется, были випилены

Comment: с ангуляровского сайта можно перейти на планкер с примером актуальной версии и его форкнуть и подредактировать

Comment: @Grundy, удалось, разобрался )) сорри, что так долго отвечал. Вот ссылка: http://plnkr.co/edit/qyqjLRPapAbK0qxITTnq
Вот если в app.module закомментить директиву, а в dashboard.module вписать, то все заработает

Comment: на самом деле не совсем все заработает: эту директиву можно будет использовать только внутри модуля dashboard

Comment: @Grundy, Ну да )) я имел ввиду что заработает внутри dashboard, но отвалится в app ))
Вчитался в доку, и, кажется, нашел как это сделать ) Делается это через создание нового модуля, к примеру, CommonDirectives и в нем объявляем все нужные директивы, там же делаем их экспорт, и этот модуль импортим в те, в которых будем использовать директиву)

Comment: пока у тебя таким модулем является Dashboard, так что можешь сделать там секцию exports и импортировать его куда нужно